# jQuery: remove or hide overlay div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an `overlay div` using the following code when an image thumbnail is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    jQuery(".test-popup-link").click(function(e) {

       var overlay = jQuery('<div align="center" id="overlay"><img id="imgBig" src="" /></div>');
overlay.appendTo(document.body);
//jQuery('#overlay').load(this.href);

var imgs = (this.href);

jQuery('#overlay #imgBig').attr("src", imgs)
        return false;
    });




});


</script>
```

This works fine.

Now i need to remove or hide the overlay div when the user clicks on the `img` with the id of `imgBig`. so I tried this:

```
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery( "#overlay #imgBig" ).click(function() {
      jQuery("#overlay").remove();
    });

    return false;
            });

</script>
```

but for some reason it just doesn't work which means it doesn't hide/remove the `overlay` div!

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `jQuery(( "#overlay #imgBig" ).click(function() { ... });` You have an extra `(` after `jQuery`.

Comment: @AbraarArique, sorry. that was a typo but still doesn't work!

Comment: Try my answer. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5y1x5vm/

Answer (score 1):

The click function doesn't work with dynamically created elements. Also, id's are unique so you should only need to use #imgBig in the selector.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery( "#imgBig" ).on('click', function() {
            jQuery("#overlay").remove();
        });

           return false;
});
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't remove the overlay either!

Comment: no, i tried that as well. nothing seems to be working!!

Comment: The click function *can* work with dynamically created elements. See "Direct and delegated events" in http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: In my experience the click event doesn't get trigger if I add an element dynamically/ @H.HISTORY could you post your full code all together thats within your document.load function?

Comment: @StaceyBurns It does if you use it with the correct parameters (as per the link)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second part inside the first function, like this (I replaced Jquery with $):

```
...  
var imgs = (this.href);

    $('#overlay #imgBig').attr("src", imgs);


    $( "#overlay #imgBig" ).click(function() {
        $("#overlay").remove();
    });
    return false;
```

A JSFiddle example:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqL4yey7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

> Now i need to remove or hide the overlay div when the user clicks on
>   the img with the id of `imgBig`

Try assigning `click` event to `img` element having `src` set to `imgs`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


  jQuery(".test-popup-link").click(function(e) {

    var overlay = jQuery('<div align="center" id="overlay"><img id="imgBig" src="" /></div>');

    overlay.appendTo(document.body);
    //jQuery('#overlay').load(this.href);

    var imgs = (this.href);

    jQuery('#overlay #imgBig').attr("src", imgs);
    // assign `click` event to `img` element having `src` set to `imgs`
    jQuery("img[src=" + imgs + "]").on("click", function() {
      // do stuff
      // e.g., remove or hide the overlay div
      $(this).parent().remove();

    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `on()` or the `click()` function doesn't work with dynamically generated HTML content. Previously you could use the `live()` method but currently it's deprecated in jQuery. Fortunately, the `on()` method accepts a second argument especially for these cases. So you can use:

```
jQuery( "body" ).on( 'click', '#imgBig', function() {
  jQuery("#overlay").remove();
});
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y5y1x5vm/

Hope that solves your problem.